# Reconnect SB-Messaging Receive Location on lost connection

Tags: biztalk, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there anyway to prevent an SB-Messaging Receive Location to not be disabled if the connection to an Azure Service Bus Queue is lost?

I would like to set an 'retry to connect' property after X minutes. 
Is this possible or do I've to scan the eventlog to see if the Receive Location gets disabled and then go to BizTalk administration and enable the location manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found were adding a script that controls if the receive location is active, if it's not I start the receive location.
Added the script to the Task Scheduler.